# Why does invalid C++ map declaration not fail at compile-time?

Tags: c++, stl, compilation

Consider the following:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Key {};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    std::map<Key, std::string> key_map;
    key_map.insert(std::make_pair(Key(), "hello"));

    return 0;
}
```

Clearly, this will not compile, since `Key` does not provide a less than operator. However, if I comment out the second line of `main()` (leaving only the `map` declaration), it compiles.

**Question**: Why is this? Shouldn't the template `std::map<K, V>` enforce the constraint that `K` provide a less than operator, upon declaration?

Answer (score 5):

The map, as you've written it, has a comparison function of type `std::less<Key>`.  Until you do an operation that attempts to use that comparison function, the code is fine.

The default constructor creates a map with no entries, so it makes no comparisons.  When you insert, it needs to do comparisons, so it tries - and you get a compile error.

Comment: To put it another way, declaring a map does not attempt to instantiate the corresponding `insert()` method. There's no reason to instantiate methods that aren't used. The class and its default constructor instantiate just fine, but `insert()` does not.

Comment: Exactly, @cdhowie